# Find consecutive item count with condition in JS

Tags: javascript

I have an array and I want to return the maximum consecutive count of the items which are bigger than 60 from the array. Here, the expected output should be 3. My current implementation is like this:

```js
let arr = ['80', '70', '11', '88', '90', '61'];

function processInput(arr) {
  var total = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > 60) {
      total++;
    }
    console.log(total);
    break;
  }
  return total;
}

processInput(arr);
```

I'm not sure if I should use `break` here or not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you need not the `consecutive count` but rather the `highest consecutive count`. If this what you need, then you will necessarily have to loop through the entire array; and hence, `break` will not apply.

Comment: yaah i just edited with maximum @jsN00b

Comment: in the current implementation, there is no condition to check if the array elements being counted towards `total` are "consecutive".

Comment: I agree that you'll need to get the maximum consecutive count. So you'll need to reset your count at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```js
let arr = ['80', '70', '11', '88', '90', '61'];

function processInput(arr) {
  
  let initialValue = 0;
  const initialValuesArray = [];
 
  arr.reduce((prev,current) => {
   if(current > 60)
    {
      initialValue += 1; 
      initialValuesArray.push(+initialValue) 
    }
   else
    { 
      initialValue = 0;
    }
  }, 0);

  const maxValue = Math.max(...initialValuesArray)
  return maxValue;
}

const result = processInput(arr);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `reduce()` in this answer. You are just using it for the sake of iterating `arr`. If all you need is iteration, use `forEach()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const maxConsec = (arr = [], limit = 0) => {
  // two variables: max-count, and count, both set to initial 0
  let cMax = 0, c = 0;
  // iterate thru the array
  for (const elt of arr) {
    // if elt is above "60" (ie, limit)
    if (elt > limit) c++;   // increment count
    else c = 0;             // else, reset count back to 0
    // if current count greater than "max-count"
    if (c > cMax) cMax = c;     // store current count as max
  }
  // return max-count
  return cMax;
};

let arr = ['80', '70', '11', '88', '90', '61'];
const limit = 60;

console.log(
  'maximum consecutive array elements above', limit,
  'are\n', maxConsec(arr, limit)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added to the snippet above.

**EDIT**
Adding a generic version based on comments (by [3limin4t0r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3982562/3limin4t0r)) below:

```js
// get max consecutive elements matching condition
// by default, condition is to check for "n" greater than 0
const maxConsec = (arr = [], checkCondition = n => n > 0) => {
  // two variables: max-count, and count, both set to initial 0
  let cMax = 0, c = 0;
  // iterate thru the array
  for (const elt of arr) {
    // if elt matches the condition
    if (checkCondition(elt)) c++;   // increment count
    else c = 0;             // else, reset count back to 0
    // if current count greater than "max-count"
    if (c > cMax) cMax = c;     // store current count as max
  }
  // return max-count
  return cMax;
};

let arr = ['80', '70', '11', '88', '90', '61'];
const limit = 60;

console.log(
  'maximum consecutive array elements above', limit,
  'are\n', maxConsec(arr, n => n > limit)
);

// using the generic version to check for max consecutive
// array elements that are greater than lowercase "k"
console.log(
  'max consecutive array elements greater than', "k",
  'are\n', maxConsec(
    ['m', 'n', 'k', 'o', 'r', 'q', 'y'],
    el => el > 'k'
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: `maxConsec()` could easily be more generic by accepting a predicate callback instead of a `limit`. Such that you can call `maxConsec(arr, n => n > 60)` You can get this working if you rename `limit` to `fnShouldCount` and change `if (elt > limit)` to `if (fnShouldCount(elt))`

Comment: @3limin4t0r, thank you for the suggestion. Added a second version. Also, added an example where we can use that version for an array of letters. I think this version can be made to work with array of objects as well; once we set the callback/condition function appropriately.